# Getting Different toolbar Controls in tinymce in rails 2 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Using tinymce editor for designing a reports . So i am facing problem in tinymce tollbar links like as shown in below image ..[image: tinymce_editor]

As i am getting rectangular box for inserting image in the toolbar . I getting different Designs for different properties of toolbar..
I want to display links in tinymce standard format .. Plz help me out from this ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
fontsize_formats: "6pt 7pt 8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 26pt 36pt",
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.addButton('report_design', {
    type: 'menubutton',
    text: 'Variables',
    icon: false,
    menu: [

      {text:'Student Basic Data', menu:[<% for data in @student_basic_data %>{text:'<%= " #{t(data)}" %>', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= data %>\%</i>');}},<% end %>]},
      {text:'Previous Institute Data', menu:[<% for data in @student_previous_data %>{text:'<%= " #{t(data)}" %>', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= data %>\%</i>');}},<% end %>]},
      {text:'Student Additional Data', menu:[<% for record in @student_additional_data %>{text:'<%= " #{record.name}" %>', onclick: function() {editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= record.name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_") %>\%</i>');}},<% end %>]},

      {text:'Parent Data', menu:[<% for data in @parent_data %>{text:'<%= " #{t(data)}" %>', onclick: function() {<%if data != "parent-category"%>editor.insertContent('<i>$%<%= data %>\%</i>');<%else%>
                  editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Parent Category',
                    width : 270,
                    height : 70,
                    body: [
                      {type: 'listbox',
                        //name: 'align',
                        label: 'Select :',
                        onselect: function(e) {
<%= remote_function(
  :url => {:controller=>"design_custom_reports",:action => "parent_category"},
  :with => "'category_id=' + this.value() " )
%>
                        },
                        values: [
                           {text: 'Select', value: 'select' },
                          <% for category in @parent_categories %>
                          {text: '<%= category.name %>', value: '<%= category.id %>'},
                          <% end %>
                        ],
                         onPostRender: function() {
            // Select the item
            this.value('<%= GuardianCategory.find(@custom_report.category_id).id unless @custom_report.category_id.nil? or @custom_report.category_id == 0 %>');
                       }

                      }
                    ]
                  }); <% end %>}},<% end %>]},
    ]
  });
},

plugins: [
  "hr image fullpage advlist autolink lists  charmap print preview anchor",
  "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
  "insertdatetime table contextmenu paste ",
  "emoticons print textcolor"
],
toolbar: "image fullpage | undo redo | fontsizeselect | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor | report_design "  });</script>
```